# Yesod - Persistent - getting migrations sql instructions

Tags: haskell, yesod

I am using `persistent-odbc`, and would like to know how to get the SQL instructions to run manually the create table instructions, instead of automatically doing the migrations.

Comment: Not sure about ODBC, but try running `printMigration` instead of `runMigration`. That will tell you the query that you need to manually run.

Comment: @Sibi It solved my problem, I think you should make an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [printMigration](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/persistent-2.2.4/docs/Database-Persist-Sql.html#v:printMigration) to see what migrations you have to manually run. Just replace the `runMigration` function with `printMigration` and it should do the job.